# How do I configure subdomain url as one.mysite.com/subdomain1

Tags: subsites

I am a Drupal Developer currently working on Drupal 7.15 multi domain site. In my site, I have already installed Domain module and configured the domains as:

- Main domain - mysite.com (say 1st level)
- Sub Domains - one.mysite.com, two.mysite.com, ... (say 2nd level)

Now I need the 3rd level Domains as:

```
one.mysite.com/subdomain1, 
one.mysite.com/subdomain2, 
one.mysite.com/subdomain3.
```

But my control panel only has the option of setting this as `one.subdomain1.mysite.com`

Can any one help on this. Either how to configure the subdomain as of my requirement or else how to re-write the url?

Thanks

Comment: http://browse-tutorials.com/tutorial/drupal-7-multi-site-localhost-xampp-or-windows-example

Answer (score 0):

The [Subfolders Domain](https://drupal.org/project/subfolders_domain) module sounds like it'll handle what you're after. Additionally, you may want to read through [my blog entry](http://yuriybabenko.com/blog/drupals-domain-access-and-sites-in-subfolders) about serving Domain Access-controlled sites from subfolders instead of subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the server side configuration.The sub folders module is for the purpose of sub directory multi sites configuration. And this will not be useful for this scenario I think.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, there are many ways to achieve this. I am just listing a few that come to my mind.

- Check out the settings.php, it has some info on this. I think using that and .htaccess we can achieve this.
- You can also do this by configuring the Virtualhost in a way that achieves this type of setting for you.
- I also have used services like pound, using which we can direct each request based on our requirement.